# Counting the number of recurring substrings in a range of cells with a cell formula

Tags: string, count, google-sheets, substring, formula

I’m attempting to tally the occurrences of substrings that appear within a range of cells in a Google Sheet column, but I have a small complication which is preventing quick and easy solutions from calculating the correct totals.  I put together a relatively simple example table below (sorry for the formatting) to demonstrate:

***Column A:* Names**       | ***Column B:* Occurrences** | ***Column C:* List**

*A2:* Adam               | *B2:*  [Blank] | *C2:* Charles; Adam

*A3:* Bob                | *B3:* [Blank]  | *C3:* Adam

*A4:* Charles            | *B4:* [Blank]  | *C4:* Smith, Charles

*A5:* Smith, Charles     | *B5:* [Blank]  | *C5:* Bob Evans

*A6:* Bob Evans          | *B6:* [Blank]  | *C6:* Smith, Charles; Charles; Bob

*A7:* [Blank]            | *B7:* [Blank]  | *C7:* Bob Evans; Charles; Bob

*A8:* [Blank]            | *B8:* [Blank]  | *C8:* *[etc.]*

The names that I’m searching for are in Column A.  Column C has the actual list, where each name that appears (as found in Column A) is offset from other substrings with semicolons.  For reference, Column C is--in my original worksheet--several hundred rows deep and will continue to grow as more data is added.

Now, I’ve used

```
=COUNTIF(C$2:C$7," * "&A2&" * ")
```

in B2 and so on to count the number of cells in which a name occurs, but it doesn’t get the totals right when one string from a cell in Column A appears as a substring elsewhere in Column A.

***Column A:* Names**       | ***Column B:* Occurrences** | ***Column C:* List**

*A2:* Adam               | *B2:*  2 | *C2:* Charles; Adam

*A3:* Bob                | *B3:* 3 *[incorrect]*  | *C3:* Adam

*A4:* Charles            | *B4:* 4 *[incorrect]*  | *C4:* Smith, Charles

*A5:* Smith, Charles     | *B5:* 2  | *C5:* Bob Evans

*A6:* Bob Evans          | *B6:* 2  | *C6:* Smith, Charles; Charles; Bob

*A7:* [Blank]            | *B7:* 2  | *C7:* Bob Evans; Charles; Bob

For example, although the exact string I need from A3 (“Bob”) appears only twice in the Column C list, the "COUNTIF" formula in B3 also includes C5’s “Bob Evans” (but does not count the “Bob” at the end of C7’s contents, because that cell has likewise already been counted for its “Bob Evans”).  In the same vein, the count for “Charles” includes all cells which might only have “Smith, Charles” when it should only find “Charles.”

I imagine that a solution could involve "SPLIT" or "REGEXEXTRACT" to count only the substrings as they appear precisely in their Column A cells, but my attempts haven’t turned up the correct totals so far.  Any guidance on how to get the right results with this setup (substrings separated by semicolons and using a cell formula to search the range of that column) would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B3:

```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3="","",(SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(REGEXREPLACE($C$3:$C$15,"(\w+),{0,1}\s+(\w+)","$1$2"),".*(^|\s)"& trim(REGEXREPLACE($A3,"(\w+),{0,1}\s+(\w+)","$1$2"))&"(;|$).*")))))
```

- We use `REGEXREPLACE` to find double names like `Smith, Charles` and combine them into a single entity ( Both in A3(Names Column) and C3:C7( List column)
- Then we use `REGEXMATCH` to find whether the modified A3 matches in any of modified C3:C7
- Then, We add them using `SUMPRODUCT`

**NOTE:**  *If you have given all the formats correctly (including number of spaces, `,` and `;`, This will work perfectly. If you've messed up in your question, Then this will not work and you will have to figure out how to adapt this to your actual format.*

Comment: That formula does work perfectly for what I provided, though you made a good point on formatting; I may have oversimplified my example.  I’m drawing the cells in column A from name and subject headings in the Library of Congress’ authority records (http://id.loc.gov/).  Some of these headings include "()" and "?", which appear to prevent the formula from recognizing those cells.  “Act (Philosophy)” and “Thomas, Aquinas, Saint, 1225?-1274” aren’t counted, for example.  I imagine that’s those punctuation marks being read as regular expression language instead of as part of the cells’ strings?

Comment: Yes. You need to escape them. You need to regexreplace them `?` with `\?` and so on. You might need to use double escape regex like  \\  to escape the  \ and so on. Better way would be to remove all them and make them all a single string `REGEXREPLACE ("([\(\)\?])", "")` Figure it out:) regex101.com

Comment: I've been puzzling over how to implement the REGEXREPLACE aspect for the last couple of days, but I haven't been able to successfully include it like you suggest.  Could you tell me how I should go about that properly?

Comment: A simpler step by step approach is to use a helper column for A&C, Say E&G respectively. Put all unwanted characters in this formula with a escape character \ . E2= `ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE (A2:A500,"([\(\)\?])", "")` This will remove all  `(`, `)` and `?` . Hope it helps.

Comment: I think that did the trick; calculating now takes a while when values are changed or added, but it's getting them right as far as I can tell.  Thanks!